# Get Facebook reactions total_count for each type of reaction

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Graph Api 2.6 with the new Reactions edge,
Is there way to get the summary that include total_count for each reaction ?

I mean, something like this :

```
"summary": {
      "total_count": 51,
      "total_count_HAHA":23,
      "total_count_LOVE":28,
      "viewer_reaction": "NONE"
    }
```

there is only "total_count" right now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
20531316728_10154835146021729?fields=
    reactions.type(LIKE).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(like),
    reactions.type(LOVE).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(love),
    reactions.type(WOW).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(wow),
    reactions.type(HAHA).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(haha),
    reactions.type(SAD).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(sad),
    reactions.type(ANGRY).summary(total_count).limit(0).as(angry)
```

Comment: Not possible. This was possible only before v2.1 `"message": "Syntax error \"Field reactions specified more than once. This is only possible before version 2.1\" at character 165:`

Comment: @LuckyMurari I just updated the api call. This one works.

Comment: this works perfect. thanks to this man. btw. where did you find this?

Comment: `.summary(total_count)` makes this a little longer than it needs to be. This is a boolean flag, so `.summary(1)` does the job.

Comment: Still wondering where you found this or how you came up with this.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to make multiple API calls for each reaction type...  If you limit your reactions to type=HAHA, the total_count will only count HAHAs.  Certainly not the most efficient approach, but workable depending on what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: you mean batch request for 5 requests for each type ?

How can you get  total_count for 1 type of reaction only ? can you write the graph api request ?

Comment: Got it.
101544000571_10154237487125572?fields=reactions.type(HAHA).limit(0).summary(true)

but still, I hope Facebook let us get all the counts in 1 request.
tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested request.

request url should be like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{id}?fields=reactions.type({reactiontype})[,reactions.type({reactiontype})]
```

If you want to get total count of each reaction then you can add summary(total_count) end of each request.

An example

```
reations.type(LIKE).summary(totalCount)
```

If you want to limit data you can use limit keyword as well.

```
reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(totalCount)
```

And finally you can rename response node using "as" keyword

```
reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(totalCount).as(like_count)
```

A sample usage and response

Request Url
https://graph.facebook.com/1230378837038354?fields=reactions.type(LIKE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(like),reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(true).as(love)&access_token=

Response

```
{
   "like": {
      "data": [

      ],
      "summary": {
         "total_count": 342
      }
   },
   "love": {
      "data": [

      ],
      "summary": {
         "total_count": 165,
         "viewer_reaction": "NONE"
      }
   },
   "id": "1230378837038354"
}
```